# There is a way to mark the fanpage in a fanpage post with Facebook's C# SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-page

I've tried to mark my fanpage in my posts by many ways:

- Adding [@pageid]
- Adding [@pagename]
- Adding {*pageid*}
- Adding {*pagename*}
- Adding a property message_tags in the post object

But it doesn't work.
Someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the review process for that. Check out the changelog and search for "Pages can mention other Pages when publishing via API": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

It includes a link to the review docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#pagementions

Basically, you can only mention a Page if an Admin or Developer of your App manages that Page without the review process.

That being considered, it should be explained how to actually mention Pages here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#pages

> @[page-id]
>
> or
>
> @[page-url]